# IDLE not opening from terminal

Tags: python, lxterminal

When I type the `sudo idle` command into the terminal it returns this error message.

```
Client is not authorized to connect to ServerTraceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/idle", line 5, in <module> main()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/PyShell.py, line 1427, in main
root = Tk(className="Idle")
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1712, in _init_
self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, want
objects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":2.0"
```

I am using Raspbian Wheezy and a TightVNC server to run my Pi.

Comment: Does it work withoud sudo?  Unless you are doing something unusual you should no longer be using sudo with Python.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to `/etc/sudoers`

```
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
Defaults    env_keep += "DISPLAY"
Defaults    env_keep += "XAUTHORITY"
```

And this to `~/.bashrc`

```
if [ -z "$XAUTHORITY" ]; then
    if [ -e $HOME/.Xauthority ]; then
        export XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority;
    fi;
fi
```

Got it from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286705/tkinter-through-vnc-without-physical-display

Comment: Thanks guys, ill check it out later and let you know what happens :)

Comment: This is probably the correct answer. Don't we all love "contributors" who ask questions, promise to follow up and then disappear?

Answer (score 0):

I think usually the direct video output from the Pi (either over analogue or HDMI) occupies display `:0`. The error is talking about display `:2.0` which to me suggests that you have two VNC servers running, one on `:1.0` and one on `:2.0`. This could cause confusion - especially if there is no client connected to `:1.0` (I don't think it will even open anything there as there is nothing to 'show' it and will therefor error out).

Try stopping all VNC servers and starting one and reconnect from your viewer.

Answer (score -1):

you can always open IDLE by just typing in

```
idle
```

Comment: Doesn't this beg the question?  The OP stated that they entered this at the command line. If you're drawing a distinction because you didn't do it with `sudo`, you should explain why that's significant.